# Taking websites as keyboard input?

Tags: java

Here is the problem I was given:
Write a program that takes website names as keyboard input until the user types the word 'stop'. The program m just also count how many of the website names are commercial website names (i.e., end with .com), and output that count.

The problem that keeps occurring is even if I type the word stop as input, it is still saying to "enter the next site." I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Can anyone help? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NewClass 
{
 public static void main( String [] args)

{

    int numberOfComSites = 0;
    String commercialNames = "com";
    final String SENTINEL = "stop";
    String website;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a website, or 'stop' to stop > ");
    website = scan.next();

    String substring = website.substring(website.length()-3);

    while (website != SENTINEL)
    {
        if(substring == commercialNames)
        { numberOfComSites++;
        }
        System.out.print( "Enter the next site > ");
        website = scan.next();
    }

         System.out.println( "You entered" + numberOfComSites + "commercial websites.");
        }




}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using reference equality `==` to compare strings. You strings are from different sources. `SENTINEL` comes from constant pool, while `website` comes from user input. They are always different as references.

To compare strings by value, the `equals` method should be used. In your case you, should replace

```
while (website != SENTINEL)
```

by

```
while (!SENTINEL.equals(website))
```

Notice that we compares constant with user input. This address a problem when `website` is `null`. This is not the case in your code, but it is a sign of good style.

See [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
while (website != SENTINEL)
```

with

```
while(!website.equals(SENTINEL))
```

`website` is of `String` type and is not a primitive type. So you need to use `equals` method to compare `String`. `==` is used for reference comparison.

> Refer this for more details [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)